# How can I get the queue to snap-grid-flip into place?

Tags: reactjs

This is my code for the queue please only answer if you personally know me and are fimiliar with the project.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import InputQ from './InputQ';
import ListQ from './ListQ';
import './Admin.css';

const AdminQueue = () => {
    return (
        <Fragment>
            <InputQ />
            <Link to="/">
                <i className="fas fa-home float-right mt-3 mb-3" aria-hidden="true" />
            </Link>
            <Link to="/signin">
                <i className="fa fa-lock float-right mt-3 mb-3 mr-3" aria-hidden="true" />
            </Link>
            <ListQ />
        </Fragment>
    )
}

export default AdminQueue;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you have to do is import this make sure download with npm:

```
import SGF from 'react-sgf-dom';
```

And Wrap what you want to SGF with the tags:

```
const AdminQueue = () => {
    return (
        <SGF>
            <InputQ />
            <Link to="/">
                <i className="fas fa-home float-right mt-3 mb-3" aria-hidden="true" />
            </Link>
            <Link to="/signin">
                <i className="fa fa-lock float-right mt-3 mb-3 mr-3" aria-hidden="true" />
            </Link>
            <ListQ />
        </SGF>
    )
}
```